# How to reload a webpage after a specific time without refresh the page(address bar will not be refresh) by jquery/ajax

Tags: php

It will be implemented in PHP. Now it is implemented by the following way.

```
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
```

Now it refreshed the addres bar...but I don't want to refresh the address bar.....

Answer (score 1):

if you want to reload the page , the whole url will be reloaded, you can't do anything about that

but if you want to reload some specific location of the webpage which is getting data form database 
then you can by just calling jquery ajax which will get updated data from database.

this technique is used by many websites to update the time of post or comment